# Duden Differences Between "an" and "in"

Tags: standard-german

Duden lists "stellt unabhängig von räumlichen oder zeitlichen Vorstellungen eine Beziehung zu einem Objekt oder Attribut her" as a definition of "an" and "stellt eine Beziehung zu einem Objekt her ... unabhängig von räumlichen, zeitlichen oder modalen Vorstellungen" as a definition of "in." Can someone clarify the differences between the uses? (Preferably with some examples?)

https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/in_innen_innerhalb
https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/an_Praeposition

Answer (score 6):

You can click on the definition or just scroll down the page to get to the examples, which look something like this.

> Der Schlüssel steckt **in der Tasche**. (local)
> Sie steckt den Schlüssel **in die Tasche**. (directional)
> **Im Sommer** machen wir Urlaub. (temporal)
>
> Die Leiter lehnt **am Baum**. (local)
> Er lehnt die Leiter **an den Baum**. (directional)
> **Am Wochenende** backe ich einen Kuchen. (temporal)

In all of the above examples, the preposition contributes to the meaning of the sentence in the expected way, which I have glossed as local, directional, or temporal.

However, if you look at prepositional objects, the preposition is devoid of meaning (and this is what Duden means by the clumsy phrase *unabhängig von räumlichen oder zeitlichen Vorstellungen*).

> Sie hat sich **in ihn** verliebt.
> Er konnte sich **an nichts** erinnern.

This is the reason why, if you google ["Verben mit Präpositionen"](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22Verben+mit+Pr%C3%A4positionen%22), you get these delightful lists you can then try and memorize.

Answer (score 5):

This is not a proper answer, but the difference is that prepositions are mostly idiomatic in collocations and have to be learned, preferably with a post-hoc justification for the virtual direction/position that is implied, just as you said "differences *between* the uses" instead of "*of*".

Example:

> *In* diesem Sinne, denke ich lieber *an* etwas anderes, während es *an* den Lesern liegt, soweit es *in* deren Macht liegt, die Unterschiede *zwischen* (oder auch "*Unterschiede in*" oder "*an*") verschiedenen Beispielen zu finden.
>
> *In* that sense, I rather think *of* something else, while it is *on* the readers, as far as it is *in* their power, to find the differences *between* various examples.

This is easy to learn, as long as it agrees with the English forms, but otherwise an easy tell to make out foreign speaker status, because the collocation is often not logical, but strict--or at least it's not anymore directly apparent how it could have been logically derived.

Answer (score 1):

As a starting point for understanding, the German "in" is the equivalent of English "in" and "into" (in German those two are distinguished by grammatical case), while "an" could be roughly translated as "at" (even though this does not cover all occurrences). Keeping that in mind will probably help you to understand the answers of David Vogt and vectory, which in my opinion are good but did leave out the very first step.